# Cannot resolve symbol 'Point', 'Size', 'PointCollection'

Tags: wcf, xaml, workflow-foundation, resharper-6.0

ReSharper 6.1 (as apposed to Visual Studio itself) is telling me there are errors in my WCF Workflow XAML file.

- Cannot resolve symbol 'Point'
- Cannot resolve symbol 'Size'
- Cannot resolve symbol 'PointCollection'

Although it compiles without any problems and appears to work I'd like to track down the cause of the errors. StyleCop obviously knows (or thinks it knows) something that Visual Studio doesn't.

This is an example of the code giving me the errors:

```
            <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
              <scg3:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
                <av:Point x:Key="ShapeLocation">179,251</av:Point>
                <av:Size x:Key="ShapeSize">242,58</av:Size>
                <av:PointCollection x:Key="ConnectorLocation">300,309 300,339 270,339 270,441 300,441</av:PointCollection>
              </scg3:Dictionary>
            </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
```

And these are the namespace declarations:

```
<Activity
    mc:Ignorable="sap"
    x:Class="Hydra.Sales.Workflows.CreateCustomer"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities"
    xmlns:av="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:hcid="clrnamespace:Hydra.Common.Infrastructure.DataContracts;assembly=Hydra.Common.Infrastructure"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Hydra.Sales.Activities.Associations"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:mv="clrnamespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic;assembly=System"
    xmlns:mva="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities;assembly=System.Activities"
    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:s1="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System"
    xmlns:s2="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Xml"
    xmlns:s3="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Core"
    xmlns:s4="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.ServiceModel"
    xmlns:sa="clr-namespace:System.Activities;assembly=System.Activities"
    xmlns:sad="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Debugger;assembly=System.Activities"
    xmlns:sap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities/presentation"
    xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System"
    xmlns:scg1="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System.ServiceModel"
    xmlns:scg2="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System.Core"
    xmlns:scg3="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:sd="clr-namespace:System.Data;assembly=System.Data"
    mlns:sl="clr-namespace:System.Linq;assembly=System.Core"
    xmlns:st="clr-namespace:System.Text;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
```

The project has references to (among others):

- `System System.Activities`
- `System.Code`
- `System.Xaml`
- `System.Xml`

Adding a reference to `WindowsBase` reduces the list of errors down to `Cannot resolve symbol 'PointCollection'` but I'm not convinced it's the correct solution.

Comment: Bug report is here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-305121

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState type is a design time artifact that comes from System.Activities.Presentation.  It has no affect on the workflow at runtime.  In fact we have a sample that shows you how to remove it.  You can safely ignore these Resharper errors.

[Removing the View State the Designer Adds to an XAML File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624144.aspx)